# Why is my JUnit test not running in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

It's been 3 hours now and I still didn't find a solution, even though I seem to have read all related questions already.

I am building an Android application and I just want to create a couple of simple Unit Tests that test my basic functions. I don't need to test any Android related logic or activity features.

So I have created a new directory in my solution in which I have created a new **JUnit Test Case**.

To keep things simple my test methods are not testing much yet, but even when doing a *Right Click > Run As > JUnit Test*, it's not doing anything.

As you can see in my screenshot the JUnit pane on the left shows my test is *terminated* but does not show any test that has been executed.

I have created a simple Unit Test in a new *Java Project* and then it's working. If I repeat the same steps in a new *Android Application Project* it's not working.

What do I need to do to run my simple Unit Tests?!

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of my non-running Unit Test]

*(My Compiler Compliance Level is 1.6)*

Comment: @BigAl Yes, I did. When I do that, the top of my *Console* says `<terminated> GpsLocationTest.testIsBetweenCoordinates (1)[JUnit] /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`. No output in the Console, not even when I add a `System.out.println(...)` in my test.

Comment: Can you try putting a System.out.println(...) in the setUp() to see if its getting that far?

Comment: @BigAl I have tried that already and it's not showing any output. It's just not doing anything… Can it be related to the fact this is an Android application? Anything special needed for that?

Comment: You can use AndroidTestCase, which inherits from junit.framework.TestCase, not org.junit.Test.

Comment: But then I would need to run the emulator in order to run my Unit Tests that are only testing code functionalities. Seems like an overkill to me.

Comment: right click -> Run As -> Android JUnit Test

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Window` -> `Show View` -> `Error Log` to see what the actual error is.
For my case it was No test found with test runner 'Junit 5'.
Then one can google for respective solution.

Answer (score 0):

You either don't have JUnit on the build path or you don't have the library (jar) at hand. Make sure both are in place.

I think you will need an unit test suite if all else fails:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ GpsLocationTest.class })
public class AllTests {

}
```

There is one more thing you can do: check whether you import the right `@Test` annotation. Restart Eclipse and clean your project if the problem persists.

You may want to refer to the [vogella guide](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html) about unit testing.

Comment: In my Package Explorer I do see JUnit 4 and in there I see the junit.jar.

Comment: Is your build path OK?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "OK"? I can launch the application without any problem.

Comment: Do you have JUnit on your build path? Check the guide I linked.

Comment: Yes, in my Java Build Path I have JUnit 4 in my Libraries. It's the Vogella guide that I followed to create my tests.. :)

Comment: Try running Eclipse with `-clean`.

Comment: Already tried cleaning my solution and it didn't work either. Strange thing is that I just created a brand new (non-Android) project that contains nothing but some quickly created class and there my JUnit test IS working. That doesn't solve the problem for my Android project though...

Comment: Did you check the imports?

Comment: Nearly three years later and I am seeing this behavior when I create a maven project with a com.zenjava javafx archetype. Similar problems with running junit and getting a <terminated> line in the console without any other additional information. Other maven archetypes work fine, but I can't find a difference in build path or other property that would indicate what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AndroidTestCase, which inherits from junit.framework.TestCase, not org.junit.Test.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Memory Issue.
Simply add these line in VM argument:
right click on Junit Test -> Run as -> Run Configuration -> Arguments -> add  "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m" under VM argument

Answer (score 0):

The java Build path of the project has Junit4.jar lets say and the Run configuration for the test you are running has Junit5 - then it causes to terminate and nothing happens.